# add a dismiss inside slides ionic 3

Tags: css, ionic-framework

I want to add a X on the top-right of my slides, and want him to be always visible.
Didn't manage to figure out the problem.

At the moment the X button is outside the slider.

my html

```
<ion-content padding>
      <button>
          <ion-icon class="close" name="close" (click)="dismiss()"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      <ion-slides pager>
        <ion-slide>
          <h2>Slide 1</h2>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide >
          <h2>Slide 2</h2>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
          <h2>Slide 3</h2>
        </ion-slide>
        <ion-slide>
            <h2>Slide 4</h2>
          </ion-slide>
          <ion-slide>
              <h2>Slide 5</h2>
            </ion-slide>
            <ion-slide >
                <h2>Slide 6</h2>
              </ion-slide>
      </ion-slides>
  </ion-content>
```

my scss

```
    .swiper-pagination-bullet {
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.50;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background: black;
}


ion-slides {
  background-color: red;
}
ion-slides .close {
margin-top: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more specifically what is not working for you? you code places X onto the left side and it persists for me OK. What is the problem exactly?

Comment: For me it's not on the left side, I want him on the top-left of all the slides :/